# Как перехватывать ссылку на изображения с помощью скрипта

Tags: php, .htaccess, изображения, router

Дана ссылка типа: `https://domain.com/catalog/img/234234.jpg?w=540&h=440`.
Как  перехватить все ссылки, какие содержать GET параметры и обработать через определенный скрипт?
Цель скрипта сжать картинку на лету( или же достать ее с кеша).

Comment: все ссылки из `/catalog/img` или вообще все?

Comment: @teran, Желательно из каталога

Comment: по моему цепочку лучше несколько изменить. запросили у вас `123.jpg?w=100&h=50`, вы ее преобразуйте сначала в `/img/resized/123_w100_h50.jpg` и переправляйте туда. Следующим правилом определяйте есть ли файл, и если  нет, то отдавайте управление пхп, пусть ресайзит. Не стоит дергать пхп раньше времени, и на случай если у вас была мысль выплевывать кэшированные файлы через пхп, то тоже не надо этого делать, делайте редирект  (то есть непосредственно когда ресайзите да, но потом редирект, а не чтение через пхп).

Comment: @teran, буфер сильно засоряет? Редиректы делать на сетевом уровне? Не будет проблем с позиционированием?

Comment: медленно отдаваться файлы будут через пхп,  и нагрузка на сервер возрастает. да и в целом не его эта работа до тех пор, пока нет требований ограничивать доступ, например, настройками приватности.

Comment: @teran, если возможность делать переадресацию не на сетевом уровне? В плане, чтобы в консоле не было статуса 3хх

Comment: пока вы флаг [R]  не установите редиректа внешнего и не будет. апач правила обрабатывает циклически пока хоть что-то

Comment: @teran, как это составить в htaccess? `RewriteRule ^catalog/img/(.+)\.(png|gif|jpg)\?w=([0-9]+)?&?h=([0-9]+)?$ https://www.domain.com/img/$1_ $3_$4.$2[L]` ?

Answer (score 1):

допустим вы запрашиваете файл `/img/123.png?w=100&h=50`. Фактически хотите проверить, есть ли у же версия с этими размерами, если есть отдать ее, если нет, то отресайзить, сохранить и вернуть.

Можете, например, хранить оригиналы в папке `/img/originals` а ресайзы в `/img/resized`.

Например, оригинал `123.png` в `/originals/123.png`, а когда запрашиваем `/img/123.png?w=100&h=50` то сохраняем результат в `/img/resized/123_w100_h50.png`

Апач файл правил прогоняет не один раз, а несколько. Флаг `[L]` говорит, что надо преврвать текущий прогон, и перейти к следующему. Если на следующем этапе никакие правила не сработали, то результат отдается клиенту.

Итак,проверяем что в запросе (несколько сумбурно написано мб). Проверяем, что запрашивается файл из `img` но не из `img/resized`, также проверяем, что указаны `w,h` (с этим на самом деле проблема, поскольку порядок аргументов может быть различен).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/img/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/resized
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (^|&)w=(\d+)&h=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^img/(.*?)\.(png|jpg)  /img/resized/$1_w%2_h%3.$2 [L,QSA]
```

Так что этим правилом любой запрос к `/img/123.png?w=100&h=50` перенаправляется в `/img/resized/123_w100_h50.png?w=100&h=50` параметры этом остаются за счет флага `[QSA]`. Обработчик уходит на второй круг `[L]`. Тут у нас уже будет `resized` и данное правило не сработает.

Теперь  папке `resized` и если файла нет, то вызывает пхп скрипт, который генерит этот файл. Если есть, то он просто отдается клиенту. Примерно так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^img/resized/(.*)   img/img.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
```

наличие в обоих запросах флага `QSA` позволит вам в php скрипте обратиться к `w,h` параметрам. Внешних редиректов тут тоже никаких не происходит. Останется еще обработать доступ к файлу без параметров `w,h` и перенаправить его в `/img/originals/`, или не хранить их там.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сегодня